# Cast To Inherited Class via Eloquent Realtionship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Thought I'd ask this as Laravel is the most elegant Framework I've come across and wondered if there was a "prettier way" of doing this.

I have a system which records books such that:

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
    public function book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Book');
    }
}
```

In the system there are number of other models which extend from "Book" such as "Novel", "Biography" etc. Is there a way for Eloquent to provide me with a correctly cast object given the right info (i.e. a namespaced class)? Currently, I am obtaining the book and the casting it using the function at https://gist.github.com/borzilleri/960035 which works but doesn't feel very "tidy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be attributed to Joshua Dwire as he set me on the path to this solution. I was intrigued by his reference to extending the standard `BelongsTo` class and make it work for me. Ideally I want to be able to call a custom relationship:

```
$this->belongsToBook('\App\Book');
```

And for that function to return a correctly cast object.

Routing through the code I found that it was the trait `HasRelationship` used by `Model` which was responsible for returning the relationship. By changing that relationship we can change the implementation and therefore the returned object.

I also wanted to replicate the same methodology that Laravel employs so have mimiced it in my own app.

With all that in mind the first step is to create a new trait `HasBookRelationship` which can be used in a model to handle the call to `$this->belongsToBook('\App\Book')`:

```
trait HasBookRelationship
{
    public function belongsToBook($related, $foreignKey = null, $ownerKey = null, $relation = null)
    {
        if (is_null($relation)) {
            $relation = $this->guessBelongsToRelation();
        }
        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

        if (is_null($foreignKey)) {
            $foreignKey = \Str::snake($relation).'_'.$instance->getKeyName();
        }

        $ownerKey = $ownerKey ?: $instance->getKeyName();

        //We change the return relationship here
        **return new BelongsToBook(
            $instance->newQuery(), $this, $foreignKey, $ownerKey, $relation
        );**
    }
}
```

This is simply copied from the existing `belongsTo` method in the `HasRelationships` trait. The key thing here is that we are going to return a custom relationship `BelongsToBook` and use that to override what is returned. The last line of the method is changed to return our desired relationship class.

The class we use is extended from `BelongsTo` but we change the `get` method to cast the object before returning it.

```
class BelongsToBook extends BelongsTo
{
    public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $child, $foreignKey, $ownerKey, $relationName)
    {
        parent::__construct($query, $child, $foreignKey, $ownerKey, $relationName);
    }

    public function get($columns = ['*'])
    {
        $objs = $this->query->get($columns);

        //iterate over the collated objects...
        $objs->transform(function($item)
        {
            //..and return a cast object with whatever method you want
            return castTheCorrectObject($item);
        });

        return $objs;
    }
}
```

`castTheCorrectObject` can be any casting function you like perhaps set up as a helper or another method in the relationship.

Once these are set up, we can empoy it in our own Model:

```
class Author extends Model
{
    use HasBookRelationship;

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToBook('\App\Book');
    }
}
```

This will return a collection of correctly cast objects and maintains the relationship.

One thing did puzzle me though. The method I overrode in my `BelongsToBook` class was `get()` and not `getResults()` as suggested by Joshua. `get()` is defined in `Relation` and is inherited by `BelongsTo` where as `getResults()` is defined in `BelongsTo`. I'm not sure what the difference between `getResults()` and `get()` is nor why I had to override `get()` rather than `getResults()`. If anyone can shed any light , it would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why you had to override get() instead of getResults(). I looked at it just now but didn't actually step through the code to see it in action. It looks like get() may be called when you're using eager loading to load the relationship the first time ($with, ->with(), etc.), while getResults is called when you use something like `$chapter->book` without eager loading.

Comment: Also note that for your `books()` function on the Author model, I'd guess you'd want to use another custom relationship overriding HasMany.

Comment: I do actually do eager load this relationship as well as access directly so will look into that. This actually chimes with another part of the system so I suspect you are right. Need to to do bit of experimentation methinks. Thinking also I could extrapolate all this into something more generic so it can be extended for other use-cases and incorporate the other relationships.

Answer (score 2):

I can see a few different options here. One would be to write your class like this:

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
    public function book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Book');
    }

    public function biography()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Biography')->where('type', 'biography');
    }

    public function novel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Novel')->where('type', 'novel');
    }
}
```

You'd then need to know ahead of time which type of book it is though. Another would be to do something like this:

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
    protected function parent_book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Book');
    }

    public function getBookAttribute()
    {
        $book = $this->parent_book;
        if (!$book) return $book; // No related book.

        if ($book->type == 'novel') return (Novel)$book;
        if ($book->type == 'biography') return (Biography)$book;

        return $book;
    }
}
```

You still have to do all of the casting yourself, but at least it's all in one place and transparent to the rest of the app, as it can still just reference `$chapter->book` For this second solution, if you ever set `$chapter->book = new Book()`, you'd also need to make sure to make a `setBookAttribute()` function.

One more complicated possibility would be to create your own custom relationship type by extending the [BelongsTo](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/fe98af11954d0e98f3c71547be63884e22cd8a8a/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php) class and overriding `getResults()` to to the casting before returning the result. This would be pretty transparent from the outside and would let you still call $chapter->book() and treat it as a relationship.

Comment: Perfect! I had the same ideas, but you got your answer written sooner. :)

Comment: Thanks Joshua - your remark about extending `BelongsTo` helped immensely. I ended up creating a new relationship so that it is the relationship that has responsibility for casting. Would be great to get your feedback on my solution.